# Comparing and Combining List Items in Python

Tags: python, regex, list

Im working on [Advent of Code: Day 2](http://adventofcode.com/day/2), and Im having trouble working with lists. My code takes a string, for example 2x3x4, and splits it into a list. Then it checks for an 'x' in the list and removes them and feeds the value to a method that calculates the area needed. The problem is that before it removes the 'x's I need to find out if there are two numbers before the 'x' and combine them, to account for double digit numbers. I've looked into regular expressions but I don't think I've been using it right. Any ideas?

```
def CalcAreaBox(l, w, h):
    totalArea = (2*(l*w)) + (2*(w*h))+ (2*(h*l))
    extra = l * w
    toOrder = totalArea + extra
    print(toOrder)

def ProcessString(dimStr):

    #seperate chars into a list
    dimStrList = list(dimStr)
    #How to deal with double digit nums?

    #remove any x
    for i in dimStrList:
        if i == 'x':
            dimStrList.remove(i)
    #Feed the list to CalcAreaBox
    CalcAreaBox(int(dimStrList[0]), int(dimStrList[1]), int(dimStrList[2]))

dimStr = "2x3x4"  
ProcessString(dimStr)
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm

Answer (score 1):

You could use split on your string

```
#remove any x and put in list of ints
dims = [int(dim) for dim in dimStrList.split('x')]
#Feed the list to CalcAreaBox
CalcAreaBox(dims[0], dims[1], dims[2])
```

Of course you will want to consider handling the cases where there are not exactly two X's in the string

Comment: That did it, it comes out correct in all my test cases (it's dimStr.split though for posterity). All of the strings have the same numbers of Xs so it should be good. Thanks for the help!

Comment: ah yes, you are of course right about dimStr instead of dimStrSplit. Glad it worked! :) Please mark this as the answer, if it fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is more likely to fit on Code Review and not Stack Overflow.

As your task is a little challenge, I would not tell you an exact solution, but give you a hint towards the `split` method of Python strings (see  the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods)).

Additionally, you should check the style of your code against the recommendation in [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), e.g. Python usually has function/variable names in all lowercase letters, words separated by underscores (like `calc_area_box`).